# Angular initializing data in $routeProvider using resolve

Tags: angularjs

I have a AngularJS application and have a requirement to initialize data from a REST API before the controller initializes. I use the "resolve" in the routeProvider and also injected the relevant value in the controller in order to make this data available. The code snippets are as follows:

RouteProvider code snippet:

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
....
.when('/account', {
        templateUrl : path + 'admin/js/pages/inputs/account.html',
        controller  : 'mainController',
        resolve: {
            data: function() {
              return $http.get(api_path + 'dashboard/get_accounts');
            }
        }
    })

myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope,$http, data, $routeParams, DataService) {
...
console.log(data);
}
```

The console is supposed display the data by I get the following error " Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dataProvider <- data "

Your help much appreciated.

Comment: Though it doesn't match the error you're getting, it looks like you forgot to inject `$http` into the resolve function for `data`. Shouldn't it be something like this: `data: function($http) { .... }`

Comment: It actually does have the $http injection Sunil, I didn't include it here for brevity

Answer (score 0):

It's because the data provider has not instantiated yet and it is instantiating the controller before the provider is ready, coming through as an undefined and unknown provider.

Try something like this that returns a promise:

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $q) {
    $routeProvider, $q
....
.when('/account', {
        templateUrl : path + 'admin/js/pages/inputs/account.html',
        controller  : 'mainController',
        resolve: {
            data: function() {
              return $q.all($http.get(api_path + 'dashboard/get_accounts'));
            }
        }
    })
```

Now, the controller won't instantiate until the promise has resolved completely. As per the documentation for $routeProvider and how it handles promises in the resolve.

[$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) on Angular's website

> resolve - {Object.=} - An optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller. If any of these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them all to be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is instantiated. If all the promises are resolved successfully, the values of the resolved promises are injected and $routeChangeSuccess event is fired. If any of the promises are rejected the $routeChangeError event is fired.

Comment: But [$http.get()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) already returns a promise. So this shouldn't be necessary and the problem seems to be elsewhere... Or am I missing something?

Comment: The reason why I say put that there is because your $http promise is not being resolved. What I recommend is taking the $http call and putting it in a service for you to resolve the promise before it is used in your routeProvider. Look at the examples here http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx and how they resolve the promise before it is included in your routeProvider.resolve.